# Display proper minute difference for overnight shift.

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need a way to tell me if a dispatch is going to be late. I'm using the Time datatype for the DeliveryTime. The problem is that our days starts a 4:00 PM and may end at 2:00.

In the sample below the datediff is saying that we are over 1:00 AM ( which we are) but I need to work on 1:00 AM next day not today's.

This is what I'm using to get the difference in minutes.

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,   CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIME()),[DeliveryTime] ) as MinuteDiff


  Customer DeliveryTime       CurrentTime           MinuteDiff
    10091   23:00:00.0000000    21:07:11.2617768    113
    10092   00:00:00.0000000    21:07:11.2617768    -1267 <<
    10093   01:00:00.0000000    21:07:11.2617768    -1207 <<
    10102   02:00:00.0000000    21:07:11.2617768    -1147 <<
    10106   22:00:00.0000000    21:07:11.2617768    53
```

Comment: is there no date in your table associated with time?

Comment: no date. just time.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the time is too early.  If so, add an offset:

```
(CASE WHEN CONVERT(time, SYSDATETIME()) <  DeliveryTime
      THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(time, SYSDATETIME()), DeliveryTime)
      ELSE 24*60 + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(time, SYSDATETIME()), DeliveryTime)
 END) as MinuteDiff
```